# OpenCV 2.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 with QtCreator

Tags: qt, ubuntu, opencv, qt-creator

I moved to Ubuntu recently and I can't get openCV working with QtCreator. As described in the OpenCv install guide I built and installed the openCV library in `/usr/local/lib`, I updated `opencv.conf` in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` and run `sudo ldconfig -v`.

But when I try to run a simple "hello world" program that shows an image in a namedWindow I get the following error:

> OpenCv Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /home/wedontplay/documenti/Library Installer/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/array.cpp, line 2482 terminate called after throwing an instace of 'cv::Excepton' what(): /home/wedontplay/Library Installer/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat

Why does Qt search in `/home/wedontplay/Documenti/...` instead of `/usr/local/lib` (it is searching in the folder where I have the OpenCv libs source code)?

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
INCLUDEPATH +=  /usr/local/include/Opencvlibname
LIBS+ = -L/usr/local/lib -[module_name1] -[module_name2] ..
```

in your `.pro` file and then try.

include module name as, for ex if its libopencvmodule1.a ,add it as `LIBS+ = -L/usr/local/lib -lopencvmodule1`

Comment: Hi, thank you i already included the libs in the .pro.
I found that the problem was a stupid error in the code.
Now it work but still have no idea of the reason i had that path in teh error...